# How to set different subplot spacing in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to reduce the spacing between the first and second subplots and increase the spacing between the second and third subplots. What should I do?

[image: Three subplots]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
a = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
b = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 3, wspace=0.3, hspace=0.2, height_ratios=[1,1],width_ratios=[1,1,1.8])


plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a)

plt.subplot(grid[0, 1])
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a)

plt.subplot(grid[0, 2])
b = b.reshape((100 * 100 * 3))
plt.hist(b, bins=30, range=(0, 1))


# plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: you could add the axes manually (`Figure.add_axes`)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a sophisticated approach, why not minimize the spacing and make the y-axis tick to the right?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
a = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
b = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 3, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2, height_ratios=[1,1],width_ratios=[1,1,1.8])


plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a)

plt.subplot(grid[0, 1])
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a)

ax = plt.subplot(grid[0, 2])
b = b.reshape((100 * 100 * 3))
plt.hist(b, bins=30, range=(0, 1))
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

# plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest you start storing both the created figure and axes as proper objects, so you can refer to them later. I personally prefer to put the subplots into a dedicated `ax={}` dictionary for later use (Think about how easily you could e.g. add labels to all subplots within a simple `for a in ax.items():` loop).

In any case, the main point here is to get the `Bbox` ([refer to the documentation for Bbox here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox)) of the subplot in question (using `.get_position()`) and next to give it a new `Bbox` (using `.set_position()`) with an updated array :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 3, wspace=0.3, hspace=0.2, height_ratios=[1,1],width_ratios=[1,1,1.8])
ax = {}
ax[0] = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,0])
ax[1] = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,1])
ax[2] = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,2])

a = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
b = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))

ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].imshow(a)

old_bb=Bbox(grid[0,1].get_position(fig))
x0,y0,x1,y1 = old_bb.extents

# to debug and see what the Bbox is before changing it
print(x0,y0,x1,y1) 
# we move the x0 anchor by 0.1 to the left:
new_bb=Bbox(np.array([[x0-0.1,y0],[x1,y1]]))
ax[1].set_position(new_bb)
# to debug and see what's going on afterwards
print(ax[1].get_position()) 

ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].imshow(a)

b = b.reshape((100 * 100 * 3))
ax[2].hist(b, bins=30, range=(0, 1))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, which perhaps has the advantage of being only a minor adjustment to your original code.

By setting `ncols=4` and putting the histogram in the fourth column, you can use the unoccupied third column as empty space, and set its relative width with the variable `spacerWidth`. Just remember that when you change `spacerWidth`, you'll likely have to adjust `figsize` as well, to maintain aspect ratio.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#For each new value of spacerWidth variable below, adjust figsize to desired aspect ratio
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 3))

a = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
b = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))

#Set spacerWidth to your desired gap size, and adjust figsize (above) to maintain aspect ratio
spacerWidth = 0.6
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 4, width_ratios=[1,1,spacerWidth,1.8])

plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a)

plt.subplot(grid[0, 1])
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a)

#The histogram is now in the column with index 3, because our spacer occupies index 2
plt.subplot(grid[0, 3])
b = b.reshape((100 * 100 * 3))
plt.hist(b, bins=30, range=(0, 1))

#Omitting tight_layout() seems to result in better results for this method 
#plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```